# Image getting out of place when content is expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-events

So, I have [this site.](http://andreawebdesign.com.br/va-test/)

When the user clicks in "Learn More" in the 1st and 2nd sections, the image on the side moves. I wish it stays where it is originally.

I don't get why this happens and don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

PS: Please check the site as the example below doesn't have the images.

```js
$("#firstP").click(function() {       
     $("#one .hidden").addClass("block");
     $("#one .hidden").removeClass("hidden");
     $("#firstP").addClass("hidden");
   });

   $("#secondP").click(function() {       
     $("#two .hidden").addClass("block");
     $("#two .hidden").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#secondP").addClass("hidden");
   });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,700|Source+Sans+Pro:300,600,300italic,600italic");



 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
 }

 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
 }

 body {
  line-height: 1;
 }

 ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
 }

 blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
 }

 blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
 }

 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
 }

 body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
 }

/* Box Model */

 *, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

/* Grid */

   

 body {
  background-color: #2e3141;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(46, 49, 65, 0.8), rgba(46, 49, 65, 0.8)), url("../../images/bg.jpg");
  background-size: auto, cover;
  background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
  background-position: center, center;
 }

 

/* Type */

 body, input, select, textarea {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16.5pt;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.65;
 }

  

 strong, b {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
 }

 em, i {
  font-style: italic;
 }

 p {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
 }

 h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Raleway, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }

  h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
   color: inherit;
   text-decoration: none;
  }

  h1 span, h2 span, h3 span, h4 span, h5 span, h6 span {
   font-weight: 200;
  }

  h1.major, h2.major, h3.major, h4.major, h5.major, h6.major {
   padding-bottom: 1em;
   border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
  }

 h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
 }

 h3 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
 }

 h4 {
  font-size: 0.7em;
 }

 h5 {
  font-size: 0.7em;
 }

 h6 {
  font-size: 0.7em;
 }



.hidden{
 display: none !important;
}
.block{
 display: block !important;
}
span.special {
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: dotted 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   border-bottom: 0;
   display: block;
   font-family: Raleway, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   font-weight: 700;
   cursor: pointer;
   letter-spacing: 0.1em;
   margin: 0 0 2em 0;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  }
/* Image */

 .image {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 }

  .image img {
   border-radius: 5px;
   display: block;
  }

  .image.left, .image.right {
   max-width: 40%;
  }

   .image.left img, .image.right img {
    width: 100%;
   }

  .image.left {
   float: left;
   padding: 0 1.5em 1em 0;
   top: 0.25em;
  }

  .image.right {
   float: right;
   padding: 0 0 1em 1.5em;
   top: 0.25em;
  }

  .image.fit {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 0 2em 0;
   width: 100%;
  }

   .image.fit img {
    width: 100%;
   }

  .image.main {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 0 3em 0;
   width: 100%;
  }

   .image.main img {
    width: 100%;
   }

  


/* Wrapper */

 #wrapper > header {
  padding: 11em 0 2.25em 0 ;
 }

  #wrapper > header .inner {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 55em;
  }

  #wrapper > header h2 {
   border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
   font-size: 2em;
   margin-bottom: 0.8em;
   padding-bottom: 0.4em;
  }


 .wrapper {
  background-color: #2e3141;
  margin: 6.5em 0;
  position: relative;
 }

  .wrapper:before, .wrapper:after {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,100 100,0 100,100' style='fill:%232e3141;' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  }

  .wrapper:before, .wrapper:after {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 6.5em;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
  }

  .wrapper:before {
   left: 0;
   top: -6.5em;
  }

  .wrapper:after {
   -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
   -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
   -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
   transform: scaleY(-1);
   bottom: -6.5em;
   left: 0;
  }

  .wrapper.alt:before {
   -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
   transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  .wrapper.alt:after {
   -moz-transform: scaleY(-1) scaleX(-1);
   -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1) scaleX(-1);
   -ms-transform: scaleY(-1) scaleX(-1);
   transform: scaleY(-1) scaleX(-1);
  }

  .wrapper .inner {
   padding: 3em 0 1em 0 ;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 55em;
  }

  .wrapper.style2 {
   background-color: #353849;
  }

   .wrapper.style2:before, .wrapper.style2:after {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,100 100,0 100,100' style='fill:%23353849;' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   }

  .wrapper.style3 {
   background-color: #3d4051;
  }

   .wrapper.style3:before, .wrapper.style3:after {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,100 100,0 100,100' style='fill:%233d4051;' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   }

  .wrapper.style4 {
   background-color: #454858;
  }

   .wrapper.style4:before, .wrapper.style4:after {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,100 100,0 100,100' style='fill:%23454858;' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="wrapper">

      <!-- One -->
       <section id="one" class="wrapper spotlight style1">
        <div class="inner">
         <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <div class="content">
          <h2 class="major">É fácil ou não éam? Ma você, topa ou não topamm. Ha.</h2>
          <p>Mah ooooee vem pra cá. Vem pra cá. Mah ooooee vem pra cá. Vem pra cá. Eu só acreditoammmm.... Vendoammmm. Ma tem ou não tem o celular do milhãouamm? Você veio da caravana de ondeammm? Você veio da caravana de ondeammm? Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm. É com você Lombardiam. Ma vejam só, vejam só. Mah ooooee vem pra cá. Vem pra cá. Ha hai. Bem boladoam, bem boladoam. Bem gozadoam. Ma vejam só, vejam só. Ha haeeee. Hi hi. Um, dois três, quatro, PIM, entendeuam? </p>
          <span id="firstP" class="special">Learn more</span>
                                        <p class="hidden">Silvio Santos Ipsum ma você, topa ou não topamm. Ma quem quer dinheiroam? Você veio da caravana de ondeammm? É com você Lombardiam. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum é muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma você vai gerar textuans ha haae. Ma vai pra lá. Ma não existem mulher feiam, existem mulher que não conhece os produtos Jequitiamm. Ha hai. Bem boladoam, bem boladoam. Bem gozadoam. Você veio da caravana de ondeammm? Estamos em ritmo de festamm. Ha hai. Bem boladoam, bem boladoam. Bem gozadoam. Eu só acreditoammmm.... Vendoammmm.
</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </section>

      <!-- Two -->
       <section id="two" class="wrapper alt spotlight style2">
        <div class="inner">
         <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <div class="content">
          <h2 class="major">Ma vejam só, vejam só. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum é muitoam.
</h2>
          <p>Ma vale dérreaisam? Você veio da caravana de ondeammm? Eu não queria perguntar isso publicamente, ma vou perguntar. Carla, você tem o ensino fundamentauam? Qual é a musicamm? Ma você está certo dissoam? É com você Lombardiam. Boca sujuam... sem vergonhuamm. É namoro ou amizadeemm? Ma você está certo dissoam? Ma quem quer dinheiroam?</p>
          <span id="secondP" class="special">Learn more</span>
                                        <p class="hidden">Mah roda a roduamm. Ma vai pra lá. Eu não queria perguntar isso publicamente, ma vou perguntar. Carla, você tem o ensino fundamentauam? Ma não existem mulher feiam, existem mulher que não conhece os produtos Jequitiamm. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum é muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma você vai gerar textuans ha haae. O Raul Gil é gayam! ... Maa O Ah Ae! Ih Ih! O Raul Gil é gayamm! É por sua conta e riscoamm? É fácil ou não éam? Ma não existem mulher feiam, existem mulher que não conhece os produtos Jequitiamm. Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm. Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm. Eu não queria perguntar isso publicamente, ma vou perguntar. Carla, você tem o ensino fundamentauam?
</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </section>

      <!-- Three -->
  </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css line 3399, you have a rule:

```
.wrapper.spotlight .inner {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

your items are align to center. if you change `align-items: center;` to `align-items: flex-start;` the image will remain in the right place.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I never heard about flex-start before :)

Comment: @AndreaSantana, me neither :)

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `align-items: center;` so when you 'expand' the 'more' section the height of the div changes and the 'centered position' also.

Try this and add a margin-top to `.image`

```
.wrapper.spotlight .inner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the opacity of the div, not the display property.
The .hidden class has "display:none" css property so will not be part of the layout.
Use a class that only has opacity:0, opacity:1 or animate directly the opacity.

```js
$("#firstP").click(function() {       
  $("#one").css("opacity", "1");
  $("#firstP").css("opacity", "0")
});

$("#secondP").click(function() {       
  $("#two").css("opacity", "1");
  $("#secondP").css("opacity", "0")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `hidden` class is as follows:

```
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Whenever you have something like that, the respective html tag will not be displayed (surprise). Now, when you remove that class, the html tag will be displayed. It will occupy some space and some contents will move right/down. So far, so good, we understand the issue.

Solution: You need to make sure your image is structurally separated from the `p.hidden`. A possible structure:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><!-- Your image --></td>
        <td><!-- Your content --></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```